# Mysql error #1452 - Cannot add or update child row

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

EDIT:

My problem was because of the tables used diffrent engines. Table Chart used MyISAM and Chartdata used InnoDB.

---

i have a very simple DB model but for some reason i cant get the Foreign Key to work. I have created the DB with Mysql Workbench and i have two rows in the 'Chart' table with id 3 and 4. When i try to add a row in chartdata i get this error:

```
INSERT INTO `charts`.`Chartdata` (

`idChartdata` ,
`param1` ,
`param2` ,
`Chart_id` 
)
VALUES (
NULL , '2012-01-10 05:00:00', '58', '3'
)
```

`#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`charts`.`Chartdata`, CONSTRAINT`fk_Chartdata_Chart`FOREIGN KEY (`Chart_id`) REFERENCES`Chart`(`idChart`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)`

I am sure that the foreign key exists, and i have tried to recreate the tables severeal times (with minor changes).

Link to DB model: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKZlh.png

**This is a SQL dump from PhpMyAdmin:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Chartdata` (
```

`idChartdata` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `param1` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `param2` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Chart_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idChartdata`,`Chart_id`),
  KEY `fk_Chartdata_Chart` (`Chart_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

ALTER TABLE `Chartdata`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_Chartdata_Chart` FOREIGN KEY (`Chart_id`) REFERENCES `Chart` (`idChart`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

Comment: Could you include the failing SQL INSERT statement in your question?

Comment: I have added it to the question.

Comment: My problem was because of the tables used diffrent engines. Table Chart used MyISAM and Chartdata used InnoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was because of the tables used diffrent engines. Table Chart used MyISAM and Chartdata used InnoDB.

Comment: and what is the solution?

Comment: I assume i changed one of the tables engine, so they would match. Too many years ago to really know, but that is my guess.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `NULL` in your `INSERT` query since the column `idChartdata` is set to `Auto_Increment` and try again.

```
INSERT INTO `charts`.`Chartdata`(`param1` ,`param2` ,`Chart_id`)
VALUES ('2012-01-10 05:00:00', '58', '3')
```

Comment: That did not work, and the null is added by phpmyadmin. According to mysql you can use NULL to "explicitly assign NULL or 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a row to chartdata, with Chart_id = 3. Is there a chart with idChart = 3? Trie to add a chart with id = 3 first, then perform your query.

[edit] Nvm, you solved it already. :D